# Can I create external users in hosted GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

I have the free GitLab hosted account and I am trying to create an eternal user.  The documentation says to go to Admin > Users, but I can't see an admin option.  Here's the link to the documentation, https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html#external-users

I don't want to resort to using the API, unless I absolutely have to!

Comment: No, external users only apply when you run the instance.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately only possible right now if you have a self-hosted instance.